# Set input default value and be able to edit it later - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, input

I have an input field and I want to set a default value when the user does not write anything.

I read several answers here on Stackoverflow that suggest using ng-init or setting the default value to the scope in the controller.

Both suggestions work to set a default value, but neither of them allow the user to edit the field later. The value is always the default one.

How can I set a default value and be able to edit it later? Thank you!

My input field:

```
input type="text" ng-model="action.parameters.subject"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set an initial value using databinding with the `ngModel` directive.

In your template:

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="test">
```

In your component file:

```js
test = 'initial value'; // some initial value
```

The user will be able to change it, but it will initially hold the value of the `test` variable.